# QtCharts restart SeriesAnimation

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using an animated `ChartView` to display a histogram in a QtQuick application.
The `SeriesAnimation` is executed once at the start of the application. How can I restart the animation at a later time?

```
import QtQuick 2.7    
import QtCharts 2.1

...

ChartView {
    id: liveViewHistogramChart
    title: "Histogram"
    anchors.fill: parent
    animationOptions: ChartView.SeriesAnimation
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeLight

    ValueAxis {
        id: yAxis
        min: 0
        max: 1
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: xAxis
        min: 0
        max: 20
    }

    BarSeries {
        id: mySeries
        BarSet { color: "blue"; values: [0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.18, 0.12, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.035, 0.1, 0.12, 0.18, 0.1, 0.02, 0.25, 0.83, 0.45, 0.27, 0.1, 0.02] }
        axisX: xAxis
        axisY: yAxis
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, Qt Documentation says that type of [animationOptions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#animationOptions-prop)  is `Animation` and so link follow to [Animation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animation.html) page. But that's bug, that shoud be [DeclarativeChart::Animation](https://github.com/qt/qtcharts/blob/dev/src/chartsqml2/declarativechart.h#L88). As for the question, you can reassign `BarSet` - `barSet.values = barSet.values` as a workaround.

Comment: Reassigning works, thank you. Care to post it as an answer, so we can mark this as solved?